# how to reset the object prop when restart the vue component?

Tags: vue.js

it's a simple example : https://codepen.io/homor/pen/vYZVodj

```
    <div id="components-demo">
        <nameinput ref="nameinput" v-if="statusInput"></nameinput>
        <button @click="statusInput=true">open</button>
        <button @click="statusInput=false">close</button>
    </div>

    Vue.component('nameinput', {
      props: {
        subject:{
          type: Object,
          default: {
            name: 'homor'
          }
        },
        namey: {
          type: String,
          default: 'homor'
        }
      },
      data: function (){
        return {
        }
      },
      template: '<div>subject.name<input v-model="subject.name" type="input" /><br/>namey<input v-model="namey" type="input" /></div>'
    });

    new Vue({ 
      el: '#components-demo',
      data: {
        statusInput: true
      }
    })
```

[image]

component "nameinput" has two default props.

1. changes props value
2. close the component
3. open the component

prop namey come to default value. But prop subject.name keep the changed value.

How to let subject.name change to default value ?

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-validation) that:

```js
// Object with a default value
propE: {
   type: Object,
   // Object or array defaults must be returned from
   // a factory function
   default() {
      return { message: 'hello' }
   }
},
```

In your case, default value will be set if you do this:

```js
subject:{
   type: Object,
   default() {
      return { name: 'homor' }
   }
}
```